# How to check if twitter status update was a success using hybridAuth

Tags: php, twitter, hybridauth

I have an issue with HybridAuth that i was hoping people could give me help with.

Basically, I use it to post twitter updates as explained [Here](http://hybridauth.sourceforge.net/userguide/Profile_Data_User_Status.html).

Problem is, I wanted to check whether the tweet was sent successfully. What would be the easiest way to do this, if it is at all possible? Should I write a function? Any ideas are appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The twitter update throws an exception when the response code is not 200. So you can do:

```
try{
// update the user status  
$adapter->setUserStatus( "Hi there! this is just a random update to test some stuff" );
} 
catch(Exception $e)
{
  //echo 'Message: ' .$e->getMessage();
  // code for failure here
}
```

See also the list of response codes from twitter: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/error-codes-responses

Comment: Ah! Thanks a lot, I had like that, just wasn't sure that it threw an exception. Many thanks for the link too